# How to build a dropdown list in Excel from a comma separated list

Tags: vba, excel

I have one cell that contains a comma separated list of values, and I need to be able to use those values as a validation list. Is there any way to do this?
The list of values can be anywhere from 0 to 50 values long.

Comment: You'll need to split the contents into their own cells.  Excel's [Text-To-Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) can do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11012619/62576

Comment: if the list is not too large, just use Validation Data, List, in Source write 0,2,5,7,50

Comment: @KenWhite Your link got me to exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to split a comma separated string out of one cell into a column of cells without VBA:

Copy the cell and in Row1 enter:

```
=CHOOSE(ROW(),
```

then Paste, `)`, Enter and copy down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Assuming the name of your sheet you have to work on is "task", the source is in cell A1 and you have to add validation list in A2 for the same sheet.

- Activate VBA
- Goto VBA editor
- Create the following code for Workbook module

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     AddCSVListValidation "Task", "A1", "A2"

  End Sub

  Sub AddCSVListValidation(sheet, cellSource, cellTarget)
      txt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellSource).Value
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget) = "Select your values here"
      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget).Validation
          .Delete
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="a,b,c"
          .IgnoreBlank = True
          .InCellDropdown = True
          .InputTitle = ""
          .ErrorTitle = ""
          .InputMessage = ""
          .ErrorMessage = ""
          .ShowInput = True
          .ShowError = True
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

The result is shown below - whenever you open the workbook it will be auto-populated. Hope this helps.

You can also trap the event for the task sheet change and run the code on condition of A1 range updates to update the validation list by calling

```
    AddCSVListValidation "Task", "A1", "A2"
```

This also allows you to expand the operation to multiple source and target cells. You will need to save the book with .xlsm extension and enable macros in the more recent of excel versions.

[image]

Comment: how can u do the same for  certain range like AD1 to AD100?. What will be the formula1 then?. can u pls tell me

Comment: Try AddCSVListValidation "Task", "AD1:AD100", targetCell

Comment: Also: refer here https://analyticsdemystified.com/excel-tips/excel-dropdowns-done-right-data-validation-and-named-ranges/